# time since last event within a diff eq function in R deSolve

Tags: r

I am using deSolve in R to solve a diff eq problem.  Within the diff eq function I need to use a parameter that is dependent on the time since the last event occurring.  For example, something like this:

```
SAMPLE <- function(t, A, parms) {
    K1 <- K10*exp(-TSLE*0.1);
    dA1 = -K1*A[1] ; 
    list(dA1)
}
```

Where TSLE is the time since the last event.  All ideas are appreciated.

**edit**: Added details from comment section

One of the parameters of the diff eq is time-dependent. Prior to an event, the value is a constant. Once an event occurs, the parameter decays at some rate. So, let's suppose an event occurs at t=10. From time 0 to 9.999 the value of the parameter is K10. Starting from 10, the parameter decays with some rate constant 0.1 until it eventually reaches zero. Hence, I need to be able to calculate the time since the event occurred within the diff eq. function.

Comment: not clear what you mean here. Unless I'm missing something, in a differential equation framework, there are *no* discrete events, at least none that are endogenous (internal to the system being modeled).  Can you give us a little more context?

Comment: Some of stochastic differential equations are useful in one version of survival analysis but deSolve is not modeling SDE's.

Comment: Please provide some example data. You can share it using `dput()`.

Comment: Let me try to explain.  One of the parameters of the diff eq is time-dependent.  Prior to an event, the value is a constant. Once an event occurs, the parameter decays at some rate.  So, let's suppose an event occurs at t=10.  From time 0 to 9.999 the value of the parameter is K10.  Starting from 10, the parameter decays with some rate constant 0.1 until it eventually reaches zero.  Hence, I need to be able to calculate the time since the event occurred within the diff eq. function.  Hope that explains it better.

Comment: I have solved the problem.  You need to trick the system.  Change the code to: SAMPLE <- function(t, A, parms) {
    K1 <- K10*exp(-TSLE*0.1);
    dA1 = -K1*A[1] ; dA2 = 1;
    list(dA1)
}  
and then use an Events table to reset the system to 0 when the event occurs.  dA2 is then the time since the event.